# PagerAdapter.getItem() crash with IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have this code for FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem():

(logd() is just a static method that calls Log.d()).

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    logd("Fragment for position: " + position);

    Fragment currFragment = null;
    List<Fragment> allFragments = mFragmentManager.getFragments();
    if (allFragments.size() == 0) {

        logd("No Fragments cached.");
    } else {

        currFragment = allFragments.get(position);
        logd("Found a cached Fragment: " + currFragment);
    }

    if (currFragment == null) {

        currFragment = MyCustomFragment.create(position);
    }

    logd("Returning Fragment: Position: " + position + " Fragment: " + currFragment.toString());
    return currFragment;
}
```

But it keeps crashing with:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-07-27 10:45:44.492 6271-6271/com.example.package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.package, PID: 6271
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: MyCustomFragment{7c7e778} (5f284a0f-a00f-4be2-8098-a3e8dc65c9cb) id=0x7f09024e}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.addFragment(FragmentStore.java:67)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1563)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:405)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

This has me totally stumped. Can someone help why this crash is happening?

As far as I can make out, the same code construct works elsewhere in my app.

I did see several other SO questions with the same exception, but none that dealt specifically with Fragments inside ViewPager+TabLayout combinations.

Edit: Even this code crashes with the same exception:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    Fragment currFragment = MyCustomFragment.create(position);
    logd("Returning Fragment: Position: " + position + " Fragment: " + currFragment.toString());
    return currFragment;
}
```

Edit: Adding the code of MyCustomFragment.create():

```
public static MyCustomFragment create(int position) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", position);
    MyCustomFragment f = new MyCustomFragment();
    f.setArguments(args);
    logd("Creating Fragment at position: " + position);
    return f;
}
```

Edit:

It seems that if I return new Fragment() from getItem(), everything works. If I return new MyCustomFragment() from getItem(), I get the crash. MyCustomFragment does not even have any constructor; it relies on the default one (though I did try with a no-arg constructor that just calls super(); still the crash persists).

Comment: Can you please add the code of MyCustomFragment.create(position);?

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that within MyCustomFragment, in the onCreateView() method, the IDE-stub code of `return super.onCreateView()` was left in place inadvertently. The superclass, Fragment, returns null from its onCreateView() under certain conditions. It appears that this null return from onCreateView() was creating the problem. I inflated a test layout in MyCustomFragment's onCreateView() and now the crash is gone.

The exception looks incorrectly worded if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an already added `Fragment` in another place. When this line of code is executing:

```
currFragment = allFragments.get(position);
```

according to the `log`, it means the `fragment` in you list is already added somewhere (in a different place or very same place). In other words, in `getItem(int position)`, you can only add a new instance of a `Fragment`. So remove this code block:

```
else {

    currFragment = allFragments.get(position);
    logd("Found a cached Fragment: " + currFragment);
}
```

And this `exception` should go away.

Comment: With only this much:

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment currFragment = MyCustomFragment.create(position);
        logd("Returning Fragment: Position: " + position + " Fragment: " + currFragment.toString());
        return currFragment;
    }

I still get the exception.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code at which Exception occurs? Specifically this part: `FragmentStore.addFragment(FragmentStore.java:67)`

Comment: FragmentStore is a framework class (androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore). The relevant method is:

    void addFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        if (mAdded.contains(fragment)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already added: " + fragment);
        }
        synchronized (mAdded) {
            mAdded.add(fragment);
        }
        fragment.mAdded = true;
    }